# CLI C++ derive from C# disposable class

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, dispose

I am trying to create a CLI C++ class that derives from `HashAlgorithm`.  `HashAlgorithm` has a a `virtual Dispose(bool)` method.  I cannot override the `Dispose` method because I get a compile error stating `dispose` is a reserved keyword.  From what I read online just adding a finalizer and dtor and the compiler will take care of everything else.  I did this and the code compiles.  When I try to use I get the error below:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Declaration referenced in a method implementation cannot be a final method
```

When I look at the code the compiler generated I see it puts this sealed keyword on the method which appears to be the source of the problem.  The `Dispose` method is not really needed at all because it already exists on the base class.  Any idea on how to get around this.

```
public sealed override void Dispose()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, in C++/CLI we implement ~ClassName and !ClassName, and the C++/CLI compiler writes Dispose(void) and Dispose(bool) for us.

I tried deriving from HashAlgorithm, and I was able to get both the dispose & finalize to work. Perhaps there's a subtle difference in how you have some of the methods declared.

Here's my test code:

```
public ref class CppDispose : HashAlgorithm
{
private:
    ~CppDispose() { Debug::WriteLine("~CppDispose"); }
    !CppDispose() { Debug::WriteLine("!CppDispose"); }

protected:
    virtual void HashCore(array<Byte>^ aray, int ibStart, int cbSize) override { }
    virtual array<Byte>^ HashFinal() override { return nullptr; }

public:
    virtual void Initialize() override { }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    {
        CppDispose foo;

        Debug::WriteLine("Disposing: ");
    }

    {
        CppDispose^ foo = gcnew CppDispose();

        Debug::WriteLine("Finalizing: ");
        foo = nullptr;
        GC::Collect();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Disposing: 
~CppDispose
Finalizing: 
!CppDispose
```

So that you can see what's going on behind the scenes, here's the methods that the C++/CLI compiler wrote for us, decompiled to C# syntax. In this case, the parent class has Dispose(void) implemented, so it's not reimplemented here.

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
protected override void Dispose([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] bool flag1)
{
    if (flag1)
    {
        try
        {
            this.~CppDispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            base.Dispose(true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            this.!CppDispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            base.Dispose(false);
        }
    }
}

protected override void Finalize()
{
    this.Dispose(false);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example David.  I compared my code to your example and they are almost exactly the same.  I had dtor and finalizer as public, changed that but no go.  Only different I see now is I have code in header and cpp file.  I will try to play around with more when I get home.

Comment: I tried just now.  When I create a console app it works fine, when I try to call from unit test I get the error.

Comment: I copied my class from a console app to a DLL, and created both a C# and C++/CLI test project. Both of them were able to instantiate the test class, and get both the dispose and finalizer to run. Are you using the MSTest framework for your unit testing, or something else?

Comment: thanks for testing David.  its strange.  One more thing is the dll is 3.5 and the test is 4.0.  Not sure if that makes a difference.  I dont have time now but I try to play around with it more later

Comment: sorry I was out of work sick last couple days.  Looks like its a bug?  When I compile the mixed mode assembly as 3.5 it happens.  When I compile as 4.0 it does not happen.

Comment: Might not be a bug, might be an incompatibility between 3.5 and 4.0. Do you have both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 installed on your machine? I know that some compilation processes require the 2008 compiler, even when run from 2010. (Either way, compiling as 4.0 seems like an easy solution to make it work.)

Comment: yes I needed to install vs2008 to get 3.5 building in 2010.  I will test on another machine later on today and see if it repros